# Can I use phonegap without showing a webview?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm aware that it is possible to access native code in a PhoneGap app through plugins. But, is it possible to have a completely native interface (on Android, iOS and possible Windows Phone) that connects to JavaScript code (enhanced with the PhoneGap library) for the non-ui layers?

*The problem I'm trying to solve:*

I'm planning an app intended to be at least partly cross-platform, so that I don't have to write it three times. However, I'm also concerned about giving a native performance and appearance for the user interface.

My theory is that I can get almost the best of both worlds by writing a couple of applications that consist of a thin UI around one internal, shared codebase. As I'm fairly competent with JavaScript, I thought I'd start my research with that. If PhoneGap allows me access to JavaScript, without the webview, then I have a lot of framework code (i/o, for example) all ready for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the use of PhoneGap is limited to a WebView.

From http://phonegap.com/2012/05/02/phonegap-explained-visually/:

```
The web view used by PhoneGap is the same web view used by the native 
operating system. On iOS, this is the Objective-C UIWebView class; on Android, 
this is android.webkit.WebView.
```

It could be possible, however, to make some sort of hybrid app.  You could code a UITabBar and other native iOS stuff in Objective-C and then throw in a UIWebView for typical PhoneGap content.  If you are supporting multiple platforms, however, this would of course require extra work.

I found a video of someone demonstrating an app like this on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVvV_QYnjLo).  I found [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778505/is-the-facebook-app-built-using-a-mobile-development-framework-like-phonegap-or) very informative too.

Comment: I briefly considered this approach as well, but my instincts tell me that it would just cause me more work trying to fight the frameworks, if you know what I mean, then it would be to design the whole UI natively. Plus, I would expect it to lead to a somewhat inconsistent UI.

BTW, that video is just Sencha Touch's Kitchen Sink app, which as far as I know doesn't integrate any native widgets.